# WebPage Maker online?

Tags: content-management-system, makefile

Is there an existing CMS similar to what the WebPage Maker software can do? For those who don't know what WebPage Maker is, it's a webpage authoring software that features drag and drop functionality which allows users with minimal to no knowledge about HTML, to easily create webpages and publish it to their sites. I want to know if there's a CMS that does the same as this software already?

WebPage Maker's website is http://www.webpage-maker.com/

P.S.
I'm looking for something that I can implement on websites that I make.

Answer (score 0):

You can give mojomotor a try.. It is a paid one. You need to login as admin and then click on the page and edit. The same is possible for small layout changes too.

Comment: I'm looking for something that I can implement on websites that I make. I'll have a look at it but I doubt that it will be able to fulfill my needs since I'm aiming for mostly free or open-source...

Answer (score 0):

If you willing to learn some basic installation of other CMS rather than webpage maker, i suggest you use Joomla CMS.

---

http://www.joomla.org/

---

It's very easy to use, hv a try =)

Comment: I have no problems using Joomla, it's the clients that I'm having problems with. It may sound mean but think of the client as a really dumb computer illiterate person. Then I need to provide something as easy to use as WebPage maker but is web-based and is accessible to them anytime via their website.

Comment: You are right. Mostly our clients would be dumb and 0 knowledge with IT stuffs. But why he should bother the software? I thought they just wanted to see the product?

Comment: Well at some point the clients would want to "learn" to edit their site.